# Unix script to check file exist in the directory for more then 30 min then user get the notification email

Tags: unix

I am searching for a UNIX script to check files in directory and if file exists then I have to compare the time with current timestamp. whether file stays in directory for more then 30 min then user will get an notification email.

Comment: Check the manual for `find` and try running it from `cron`. Perhaps use `mailx` to signal the owners.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of find command will allow something like this:

```
find . -cmin +30 | while read file ; do executeTooOldFile "$file" ; done
```

However, you need to think this through. If you run this every minute, then until the file is removed, the user will get an email every minute. Maybe your test should be "-amin +30" and then you 'touch' the file (that would change it's timestamp though) so you won't send an email for another 30 minutes.

Note: 'find' and 'touch' are system commands but 'executeTooOldFile' would be your own script that includes what to do when you found too old a file. If you have access to 'cron' then you can schedule the find command directly in it, but I would create a "master" script that would contain the 'find' and execute that in cron.